# on click add dynamic text area -like object in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, text, jpanel

The title is a bit confusing, but I will be using Java and Jframe. Basically, I want to be able to click anywhere on the form and have a "text area/box" show up (maybe use a JTextField or JTextArea ?). I want the user to be able to edit, delete and move this string around as well.

I am thinking I need an actionlistener to listen for clicks on the form. Each click will call for a new text"box" to be created. I am not sure how to make this "box" editable, deleteable, or moveable by the user though.

I need a way to store the string and co-ordinate data too. Would it be a good idea to simply extend the JTextField or JTextArea to add co-ordinate information to them? I see that swing is event based, so I need some kind of trigger to "save" the text (was thinking the enter key, but I realize I'd like the user to be able to enter multi-line strings).

Any thoughts would be appreciated. I am familiar with Java but only have a bit of experience with the UI portion.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an `ActionListener` you will need a `MouseListener` to track clicks.

Sounds like you need an undecorated `JInternalFrame` with a text box in it on `JDesktopPane`.  However, I don't think you can create an undecorated JInternalFrame, maybe start with a normal `JInternalFrame` with a TextBox in it and create new frames on mouse clicks on the Desktop Pane.  Then see if you can make the `JInternalFrame` more like a `Window`.

Another route is a custom component that does everything you need.  This is possible, just a lot more custom code.

Comment: Thanks! I kept looking and found some code to make things draggable (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874360/swing-creating-a-draggable-component). Now I just need to find a way to add the text component!