# Drag and Snap JLabels in Java

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel

I'm trying to implement a drag and snap type of thing with JLabels. Basically, a JPanel launches with JLabels that are in specified boxes around the screen (all the JLabels and Boxes are the same size). Then, I'd like the user to be able to drag a JLabel into a box and have it "snap" into the box; meaning, when their mouse approaches the box, the program knows to snap that JLabel into that box.

I could do this tediously with mouse listener and mouse dragged and do lots of rendering (I've already begun this, and it's not too pretty). But I was wondering if there is something on the web that anyone knows about, or anything built into java, which would help me.

NOTE: THIS IS NOT A QUESTION ABOUT DRAG AND DROP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874360/swing-creating-a-draggable-component read this post. It shows one implementation approach for what you're talking about. A snap isn't different from a drag, it just has a set of parameters based on where the component is. I'm assuming your trying to implement something like JQuery snaping which uses steps. An algorithm isn't going to be overly complex, but "NOTE: THIS IS NOT A QUESTION ABOUT DRAG AND DROP." is not winning you any friends. Look at awt, not Swing. MadProgrammer gave you some great hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag'n'Drop is such a specialty area of requirements.

Take a look at the implementation of the `TransferHandler` API for `Swing` components.  Works really well for the built in components, takes some work to get to work in custom components but is otherwise impossible to extend (I'm looking at you custom cursor & drag graphics).

The problem is, that any toolkit/API/framework will only work within the constraints of it's target design.

You can make life a "little" easier by separating the various elements of the DnD API, registering listeners, event handling etc, so that you can focus on the requirements of the solution a little better, but, at the moment, that's about as far as you might get.

For example, the API I've written probably won't meet your needs, cause I wrote to solve a series of particular problems I was dealing with.

Just MHO

Comment: this is not drag and drop. this is drag and snap.

Comment: @CodeGuy, there's no fundamental difference. One simple uses a target when released and the other intercepts based on coordinates firing an animation. The man here just answered your question.

Comment: yes, there is a major difference. look at dragging and dropping with a JTable versus dragging and dropping with a JList...with a JTable, there is snapping that ocurrs. This is what I want, but I want it with JLabels in defined snap positions on a JPanel.

Comment: @CodeGuy yeah, it's still the same **drag'n'drop** api.  The difference is how the individual renders are dealing with the drag event.  This is your problem.  No single API will achieve entirely what you want, because of the complexities of the over all API.

Comment: @CodeGuy this is exactly what I'm saying, you're forced to use the API or do a custom implementation much lower (a huge project). You should experiment with the API and the renderers, you'll be able to achieve it. (Also, your curt responses don't encourage me to spend any time writing up an example for you, I recommend you dig in and figure it out.)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the drag and drop package: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/package-summary.html

Comment: nudge, nudge, you might like to link to Java 7 API's - this could get you a down vote otherwise ;)

Comment: Edited, thanks. I just went with the first result when I Bing'd java.awt.dnd. Didn't realize it was the wrong version.

Comment: Not "wrong" per say, but it does highlight those APIs that might have become deprecated, so even if the OP is still using an older version of Java, they will become aware of possible future incompatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for java "snap-to-grid" examples, and then modify accordingly to pair off gui components?