# how do i move the racquet using mouse event?

Tags: java

I have made a mini tennis game that moves the racquet left and right using a keylistener.

```
package mini_tennis;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Racquet {
private static final int Y = 330;
private static final int WIDTH = 60;
private static final int HEIGHT = 10;
int x = 0;
int xa = 0;
private Game game;

public Racquet(Game game) {
    this.game= game;
}

public void move() {
    if (x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getWidth()-60)
        x = x + xa;
}

public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect(x, 330, 60, 10);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    xa = 0;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        xa = -game.speed;
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        xa = game.speed;
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

public int getTopY() {
    return Y;
 }
}
```

I would like to know how to move the racquet using mouse events. For example,  when I click on the racquet using the left button it will drag the racquet left or right. Could you also include how I could move the racquet by moving my mouse left and right without pressing any buttons.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/874424/2958086

Comment: The link you provide is nothing like my code so i dont know where to change it. But thanks

Comment: you did the key events?? really?? no kiddin

Answer (score 0):

you will need an mouse listener

```
public class Racquet {
 ...

  public void moveM(int mx)
  {
    x = mx; //invoked from panel to move the racquet
  }

 ...
}
```

your panel class:

```
class yourPanelClass implements MouseListener {
...
panel.addMouseListener(this); //add listener to the panel
Racquet raq = new Racquet(); //create the racquet
...
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
       raq.moveM(e.getX()+((int)raq.getWidth()/2)); 
// get pointer position on mouse press and invoke method 
// in Racquet passing the current X location of the pointer
// subtracting half of the width of the racquet thus positioning it in
// the middle.
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent  e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
....

}
```

Comment: This code is not drag. I want to drag the racquet left and right. Not clicking  the location and then racqent move to that location. But thx tho

Comment: if you were to hold down it would move, you can add an `if()` statement to detect whether he is clicking on the racquet or not, therefore clicking anywhere would not make it jump there.

Comment: when i click the racquet, the side of the racquet jump to my pointer location. When i hold it and drag it doesn't move

Comment: i did some minor changes, check it now, change it to mouseClicked event